# error: Too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `devise` and trying the next following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery
   before_filter :is_worker

   def is_worker
     if user_signed_in?
        @email = current_user.email
        if @email && Worker.find_by_email(@email).nil?
          redirect_to '/tasksadmins'
        else
           redirect_to '/workers'
        end
     else
         redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
     end
   end
end
```

when I try to enter the site: `localhost:3000/tasksadmins`, I got:

```
Oops! It was not possible to show this website

The website at http://localhost:3000/tasksadmins seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Too many redirects

It could be temporarily switched off or moved to a new address. Don't forget to check that your internet connection is working correctly.
```

How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`before_filter` is applied to every single request. That's why it's redirecting again and again.

You might want to only filter specific actions:

```
before_filter :is_worker, only: :index
```

Another solution would be to check wether a redirect is necessary in `#is_worker`:

```
redirect_to '/workers' unless request.fullpath == '/workers'
```

**EDIT:**

Another way would be to skip the before filter for the target actions of your redirects. Example:

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :is_worker, only: :index

  # …

end
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and I got error: The website at http://localhost:3000/workers seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Too many redirects

Comment: That's because you're redirecting to the `index` action of the `workers` controller. Instead of my first solution: In your `WorkersController` you can call `skip_before_filter :is_worker, only: :index` so the redirect is send everywhere but not for `/workers`. You can apply the same for `/tasksadmins` and `/users/sign_in`.

Comment: I used what you suggested me (skip_before_filter), and in addition I added to the applicationcontroller:  before_filter :authenticate_user! above the 'def is_worker'. unfortunately, I sign up with an email that is not found in workers, and I am redirected to '/workers' instead of '/tasksadmins'. can you know why please? thank you for everything!

Comment: Maybe you should try to add some debug output to your `#is_worker` filter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

**users_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :logged_in?, only: :new

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render layout: "session"
  end
```

and

**application_controller.rb**

```
def logged_in?
    redirect_to users_new_url unless current_user.present?
end
```

When I was trying to redirect to the 'users/new' page,same error occurred.
This is just because I'm trying to redirect to the *'users/new'* page and **"def logged_in?"** is also redirecting to the same page.

Then I changed the **application_controller.rb** code like this:

```
def logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user.blank?
end
```

**Error_Resolved.**